# What is a Ambient Occlusion sample?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I've just began using the branched path tracing mode in the Cycles rendering engine and as far as I can tell, I've been getting good results in it.  But I've been confused by one particular sample type that is listed: Ambient Occlusion.  I think that I understand what Ambient Occlusion is as an effect but as far as I know, it's more of a hack to fake Global Illumination then a realistic simulation of light.  So is there something going on behind the scenes that I'm not understanding?